# how to get the first name of all childs who are born before 1999 in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have got this DB and i write queries who give me all information of husband, wife and child, how did i get all  child's who are born before 1999 **in one list**?

```
 family(
 person(tom,fox,date(7,may,1960),work(cnn,15200)),
 person(ann,fox,date(9,may,1961),unemployed),
 [person(pat,fox,date(5,may,1983),unemployed),
 person(jim,fox,date(5,may,1985),unemployed)]).
 family(
 person(nom,ros,date(30,may,1976),work(abc,16200)),
 person(shi,ros,date(22,july,1981),work(cbs,19000)),
 [person(mat,ros,date(5,aug,2005),unemployed),
 person(har,ros,date(5,jan,2007),unemployed),
 person(teh,ros,date(20,aug,2011),unemployed)]).
 family(
 person(zvi,ha,date(21,jan,1980),work(cnn,11200)),
 person(haya,shu,date(19,aug,1979),work(fox,15000)),
 [person(isi,ha,date(15,aug,1987),unemployed),
 person(riv,ha,date(3,jan,2011),unemployed)]).

 husband(X):-family(X,_,_).
 wife(X):-family(_,X,_).
 child(X):-family(_,_,Children),member(X,Children).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
dateofbirth(person(_,_,Date,_), Date).
child1999(X, L) :-
    child(X),
    dateofbirth(X, date(_,_,Y)),
    Y < 1999.
```

Comment: @user123456 look up the `findall/3` predicate.

Comment: @lurker I tried this: findall(child(X),(dateofbirth( X, date(_,_,Y)), Y<1999),L). and it's given me an error.

Comment: @user123456 please look up the `findall/3` predicate and examples. That's not how `findall` works.

Comment: findall(X,( child(X),dateofbirth(X,date(_,_,Y)),Y<1999),L). this is works.